# How do I make 6 buttons aligned and same size?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I am trying to use the design tab in Android Studio to design my XML for my homescreen, however when i try and drag a button it realigned everything on the layout, eg like in the image below:
[image: My Messy XML]

I want to arrange it so the buttons are a uniform size and aligned in a 2x3 table like the following

a b

c d

e f

I would like the image to remain in the same place as it is currently, with the text underneath also not to move.

Current XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/amityapplogo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/welcomeadmin"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/mydetails"
        android:id="@+id/mydetailsbutton"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/myhealthbutton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/policydetails"
        android:id="@+id/policydetailsbutton"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/mydetailsbutton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/findaproviderbutton"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/findaproviderbutton" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/myhealth"
        android:id="@+id/myhealthbutton"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/contactusbutton"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/findaprovider"
        android:id="@+id/findaproviderbutton"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/myhealthbutton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/visitourwebsitebutton"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/contactus"
        android:id="@+id/contactusbutton"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/visitourwebsitebutton"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/visitourwebsite"
        android:id="@+id/visitourwebsitebutton"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/myhealthbutton"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/myhealthbutton"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myhealthbutton"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Cheers in advance!

Added tablerows, now all is aligned to the left hand side:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:src="@drawable/amityapplogo" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="@string/welcomeadmin"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/mydetails"
                android:id="@+id/mydetailsbutton"
                android:layout_column="0" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/policydetails"
            android:id="@+id/policydetailsbutton" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/myhealth"
            android:id="@+id/myhealthbutton" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/findaprovider"
            android:id="@+id/findaproviderbutton" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/visitourwebsite"
            android:id="@+id/visitourwebsitebutton" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/contactus"
            android:id="@+id/contactusbutton"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Make a table layout where your table rows contain buttons.

Comment: Do you need a table format , or just buttons arranged in that manner(without table outline)??

Comment: Either way, so long as it will scale on different devices @AkshitRewari

Comment: A GridView or a GridLayout might help.

Comment: @Funkystein good shout, I used that then morphed to tablerows. Will add edit shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and let me know

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/amityapplogo"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/welcomeadmin"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/mydetails"
    android:id="@+id/mydetailsbutton"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/findaproviderbutton"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/myhealthbutton"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/myhealthbutton" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/policydetails"
    android:id="@+id/policydetailsbutton"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/mydetailsbutton"
    android:layout_above="@+id/findaproviderbutton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="36dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/myhealth"
    android:id="@+id/myhealthbutton"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/policydetailsbutton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/findaprovider"
    android:id="@+id/findaproviderbutton"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/mydetailsbutton"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/mydetailsbutton" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/contactus"
    android:id="@+id/contactusbutton"

    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/policydetailsbutton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/myhealthbutton"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/myhealthbutton" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/visitourwebsite"
    android:id="@+id/visitourwebsitebutton"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/policydetailsbutton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/mydetailsbutton"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/contactusbutton"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/contactusbutton" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is what it look without assets

[image]

Comes to this(At Paul's , with assets):
[image: Result1]

Comment: I've added the photo, have a look. All align to the left.

Comment: That's because I wasn't able to view the image assets and strings.xml while editing. All you gotta do is pull contact us to right and adjust width of button to its left.(Remaining should align accordingly)

Comment: Apologies if wasting your time, but after using tablerows, i prefer hte overall look immediately. only problem is I cannot align it in the center. Will post edit now.

Comment: That's even simpler, Use         android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
in Table

Comment: Thank you, layout_gravity worked. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

This might work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="ggggg"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/mydetailsbutton"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:text="Details" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/policydetailsbutton"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mydetailsbutton"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/mydetailsbutton"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/mydetailsbutton"
    android:text="eeeee" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/myhealthbutton"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/mydetailsbutton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/mydetailsbutton"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/mydetailsbutton"
    android:text="ddddd" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/findaproviderbutton"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/mydetailsbutton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/policydetailsbutton"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/policydetailsbutton"
    android:text="ccccc" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/contactusbutton"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/myhealthbutton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/mydetailsbutton"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/mydetailsbutton"
    android:text="bbbbb" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/visitourwebsitebutton"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/myhealthbutton"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/policydetailsbutton"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/policydetailsbutton"
    android:text="aaaaa" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: important thing is to give custom width for top buttons they should be of equal width

Comment: Custom width will set a fixed width for the top buttons(and hence all the other buttons) which will remain same on all screen size. Instead we should specify layout margins and specify other buttons to match the top buttons

Answer (score 2):

You can use LinearLayouts inside another LinearLayout just like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:text="Button1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:text="Button2" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:text="Button3" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:text="Button4" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:text="Button5" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.25"
            android:text="Button6" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

You can add the ImageView and TextView before the first LinearLayout that keeps the first two Buttons.

Comment: Relative Layout will still be required for rest of the items . therefore will need a nested layout which is not necessary here. Easier to implement without Linear Layout